# Can Tomboy import notes from a directory (eg Dropbox)?

Tags: sync, tomboy, dropbox, text, notes

I am an iOS user and use an app called PlainText to sync my notes with Dropbox. I noticed with Tomboy Notes you can sync to a local directory - upon setting this to the PlainText directory in Dropbox (the area where PlainText syncs to my Dropbox) I expected to see Tomboy recognize the plain text files in that directory.

So my question is, are there any add-ins that will allow Tomboy to watch that directory and import when plain text files are added?

Comment: Tomboy notes are not plain text, they are XML. So Tomboy will only read notes in its format.

Comment: Tomboy can be started with `tomboy --note-path /some/path` and grab notes from there. But note filenames will look like this: `109629e3-e99c-4db2-8776-ad6a7fc3adc8.note` and it's not recommended to edit them manually.

Comment: Damn :( time to start looking for some nice alternatives then. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @dAnjou: you should add this as an answer. Jordan Tomboy could "watch" for new notes, but only if they are in it's format.

Answer (score 2):

*Answered in a comment and approved as a fix by the OP:*

> Tomboy can be started with `tomboy --note-path /some/path` and grab
>   notes from there. But note filenames will look like this:
>   `109629e3-e99c-4db2-8776-ad6a7fc3adc8.note` and it's not recommended to
>   edit them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Tomboy does not actually need an import for a new installation or moving between machines.

Copy the `~/.local/share/tomboy/` folder from your existing machine and place in the same location on the new installation.

When you start tomboy all your notes will be there in the same order and structure.